# Как запустить данный JS скрипт через 3 секунды?

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, который распознает пользователей с AdBlock и показывает им сообщение, скрипт работает мгновенно, а нужно запускать его через 3 секунды. Как это сделать?

```js
function adb_checker(b) {
  if ("undefined" === typeof adblock) {
    if ("object" === typeof b) {
      var a = b.url;
      "undefined" !== typeof a && 0 < a.length && (b.redirect ? window.top.location.href = a : "object" === typeof(warn = b.warning) && ("undefined" === typeof warn.text && (warn.text = "Please disable AdBlock to continue!"),
        "undefined" === typeof warn.button && (warn.button = "Help me to disable!"),
        adb_warning(a, warn.text, warn.button)))
    }
    return !0
  }
  return !1
}

function adb_warning(b, a, c) {
  a = '<div class="smoke-base smoke-visible smoke-alert"><div class="smokebg"></div><div class="dialog smoke"><div class="dialog-inner">' + a;
  a = -1 != (img = getHelpImg()) ? a +
    ('') : a +
    ('<div class="dialog-buttons"><a href="' + b + '">' + c + "</a></div>");
  a += "</div></div></div>";
  b = document.createElement("div");
  b.innerHTML = a;
  document.body.appendChild(b)
}

function getHelpImg() {
  var b = window.navigator.userAgent,
    a = document.location.protocol + "//in-trend.biz";
  return a = -1 < b.indexOf("Chrome/") ? a + "/" : -1 < b.indexOf("Firefox/") ? a + "/" : -1
};

adb_checker({
  url: '<span></span>',
  redirect: false,
  warning: {
    text: '<p>Отключите AdBlock <br> для данного сайта.</p>',
    button: '<span></span>'
  }
});
```

Comment: Так запустите его через `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(adb_checker, 3000, {
  url: '<span></span>',
  redirect: false,
  warning: {
    text: '<p>Отключите AdBlock <br> для данного сайта.</p>',
    button: '<span></span>'
  }
});
```